# Matlab Least Squares approximation with Constraints for Two independent variables (x,y coordinates)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, linear-regression

I have a couple of binary images of outdoor paths and am required to get a fine outline of the roads, however, due to noisy pixels still remaining, I am unable to trace an accurate outline of the road. I calculated the midpoints between start and end points from `houghlines` function in `Matlab`, and have been able to separate the Left and Right points of the road. So, my idea was to fit a linear approximation of the Left and Right points so that I will be able to either remove the noisy pixels at both sides and separate out the road region cleanly.

[image: Examples of good and bad line fits of left and right sides of two roads]

**Problem:** As you can see in the pictures, the straight line that fits is not along the longest axis of the scattered (x,y) points (red) and therefore a bad fit. Some sides of the roads were very good fit. The output approximation of the [polyfitn](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn) or `polyfit` function starts along the shorter scatter regions. I have found several code examples for least squares approximation with constraint (start and end) but found examples only for 1D independent variable type problems.

Here is the Matlab code I used to produce the outputs.

```
imshow(binarizedimage320x240);        % Binary 320x240 image
rightPoints     % show rightPoint (x,y) coordinates from Hough Transform lines 

sizeRt = size(rightPoints, 1);
x = zeros(sizeRt, 1);
y = zeros(sizeRt, 1);

for k = 1:sizeRt
    x(k) = rightPoints(k,1);
    y(k) = rightPoints(k,2);
end
x               % show x values
y               % show y values


% Linear fitting
p = polyfitn(x,y,'constant x+y')    % show p
xi = 1:2:300;
yi = polyvaln(p, xi);

plot(x, y, 'ro', xi, yi, 'b-', 'LineWidth', 3);
```

**Variables:**

```
rightPoints =
  205.0000  108.0000
  205.0000  162.5000
  205.0000  276.0000
  229.0000  123.5000
  229.0000  254.5000
  204.0000   87.5000
  215.0000  265.0000
  216.0000  121.0000
  216.0000  255.0000
x =
   205
   215
   216
   229
   205
   229
   216
   205
   204
y =
  276.0000
  265.0000
  255.0000
  254.5000
  162.5000
  123.5000
  121.0000
  108.0000
   87.5000
p = 
      ModelTerms: [2x1 double]
    Coefficients: [-152.6022 1.5730]
    ParameterVar: [3.7729e+05 8.2396]
    ParameterStd: [614.2421 2.8705]
              R2: 0.0411
      AdjustedR2: -0.0958
            RMSE: 71.6719
        VarNames: {'x+y'}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem like you might find [PEaRL](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~yuri/Papers/ijcv10_pearl.pdf) by Isack and Boykov applicable for your problem.
The algorithm suggested in the paper formulates an energy minimization approach for simultaneously fit several geometric models in a noisy scenario (better than Hough or Ransac in theory).
I also believe they have code available [here](http://vision.csd.uwo.ca/code/).